# What third-party speedlite/flashes are available for Nikon?

Tags: nikon, dslr, flash, third-party

I'm looking for a flash with a **budget of < $200**. I have a Nikon D3100, and I'm a beginner with photography, who is taking some classes and wants some flexibility with a decent bounce flash.

I was surprised to find that the only Nikon flash < $200 is the $119 SB-400, which I'm concerned might be a little too limited.  But the next jump up is around $279+ to the SB-600, and up from there with the SB-700.

**I'm looking for some strong recommendations for alternative brands that will provide comparable functionality of an SB-600 at a more affordable price.**

If there are no options, then we'll consider the higher priced Nikons, or postpone the purchase 'til we have a bit more cash, so if you feel really strongly that we have to go with one of the more expensive Nikons, let that be known.

Comment: Are you looking for [TTL support](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/4645/378)?

Comment: Ya, I do think that TTL support is something that we'd want to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's one that I've looked at several times as a possibility for my next flash - although I have no personal experience with it - [the Vivitar DF383](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001ZT3DOU).

Features:

- TTL
- Swivel and Tilt
- GN45
- AF focus assist

Comment: Looks like the same flash is also sold as [Cactus AF45](http://gadgetinfinity.com/product.php?productid=17371&cat=337&page=1)

Answer (score 2):

have a look on [METZ flashes](http://www.metz.de/en/photo-electronics/product-families/system-flash-units.html) - they have wide range of products and good price/performance ratio.

Answer (score 2):

I recently bought a Yongnuo YN465 for about $80 from Hong Kong, I cannot comment on how it compares to the Nikon ones but it beats the on-board flash hands down. It has tilt, swivel, ttl and will zoom to some degree. Also has a slave function built in to fire off another flash.

Answer (score 1):

[Nissin Di622 Mark II](http://www.nissindigital.com/en/di622mii.html) seems to be the good candidate:

> - Guide Number : 44m, 145ft. (ISO 100), 62m, 205ft. (ISO 200)
> - Illumination coverage : 24-105mm (16mm wide angle diffuser)
> - Turning head : 90 degree upward, 90 degree to left, 180 degree to right
> - Power source : 4 X AA or equivalent Mi-MH, lithium
> - Number of flashes : 200-1500 flashes by fresh alkaline batteries
> - Energy saving system : 2 minutes to stand-by mode, 30 minutes to shut down after the power on or the last use of flash unit
> - Recycling time : 5 sec., with fresh alkaline batteries.
> - Flash exposure control :
>
>   - E-TTL and E-TTL II for Canon cameras
>   - i-TTL for Nikon cameras
>   - Manual(Variable power) : 6 levels : Full - 1/2 - 1/4 - 1/8 - 1/16 - 1/32 powers
> - Wireless mode :
>
>   - SD: Slave Digital (with 6 level)
>   - SF: Slave Film (with 6 level)
>   - Wireless TTL remote Channel 1 Group A (Controlled by master flash)
> - Flash Power Lock: FE lock (for Canon) / FV lock (for Nikon)
> - My TTL Setting
> - AF Assist light : Infrared LED for distance of 0.7 to 6 meter.
> - Color temperature : 5,600K (same as daylight)
> - Flash duration : 1/800sec. to 1/20,000sec.
> - Camera contact : Hotshoe , X-contact, External Synchro socket
> - Accessories included : Shoe stand, pouch

The only missing feature for me is the high-speed sync support.

Comment: Looks good too, though pushes just over my $200 limit, but may consider it since it's juuuust over by a few hairs.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to get non-TTL flash. For example LumoPro LP160 recommended by [strobist](http://strobist.blogspot.com/2006/03/lighting-101-start-here.html) is around $160, so you'd get lighting power of hi-end Nikon flash at lot lower price. Put the remaining $40 to umbrella and PC sync cord and you're done.

The downside obviously is that that flash is fully manual, so you need to adjust the power yourself. But at $200 you need to do compromises somewhere, be it power, automation, reliability or something else.

Comment: Compromise on power, automation, *or reliability*.

Comment: The Yongnuo listed below is a great example of rfusca's point.