# Where can I get the tripod-to-camera adapter for my Nikon D90?

Tags: tripod, nikon-d90, tripod-socket

I just purchased a used D90. I had a tripod but I just found that the D90 didn't have the tripod mount (the adapter to mount the D90 to the tripod). Is there anywhere online I can buy that?

Comment: The missing piece isn't specific to your D90, because all DSLRs use a common, [standard socket](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/17816/1943). Instead, it's specific to your tripod — so we need to know your tripod make and model.

Comment: So even I buy the new camera kit, usually, will that piece come with the kit? If I buy a new tripod, will the quick-release plate included in the tripod? Thanks again.

Comment: It would usually come with the tripod head. (Which may be sold separately from the tripod legs.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This has nothing to do with the camera.** All cameras have the same thread which is used to attach it to a support like a tripod.

What you are **looking for is a quick-release plate** and that is specific to the tripod head you use. If you have the exact model, you have to look it up and find out the part number for the plate. That is the one to order. For example my head is a [Manfrotto 057RC4](http://www.manfrotto.us/057-magnesium-ball-head-with-rc4-quick-release) and it uses a [410PL plate](http://www.manfrotto.us/low-pro-quick-release-adapter-plate-rc4).

**Depending on your tripod, availability may vary or it may be a special order.** If you use one of the major brands like Manfrotto, Gitzo, Velbon, Giotto, etc then [B&H Photo](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/) or [Adorama](http://www.adorama.com/) stock a good number of them.

If you do not have a model number or part number, then the best is to **bring to a store, ideally the one where you bought the head** (or tripod if it came with a head) and they will tell you the part number and order it at your request.

Comment: Thanks all for your reply. The tripod I am using is Ambico 54 Inch Tripod. Does anyone know which model of quick-release plate I should buy? Since there is no local camera store in where I live, I have to buy it online. Buy the way, if I buy a new tripod, will the quick-release plate attached too? Thanks.

Comment: If you buy a tripod that comes with a head it will come with the QR plate to match. As you get into the most expensive tripods they will come without heads as it is expected that you will be supplying your own (to meet your specific needs). Also, your tripod is cheap, go ahead and buy a new one, or buy the same one (which will have your QR plate) and then you'll have the plate and a backup tripod for when it breaks. But you should probably buy a new tripod.

Comment: Sorry but I have never heard of that brand. Try to Google it. The vast majority of times when you buy a tripod head or a tripod with head, you will get a plate. I noticed Arcatech does NOT supply plates but AFAIK, they are *the exception* because they use plates which are camera-specific. Cameras however, never come with plates because they have no idea what head you will connect them to!