# Which adapter do I need for a softbox and a speedlite?

Tags: flash, tripod, hotshoe-flash, adapter, softbox

I'm just starting with photography. Currently I'm getting my stuff together for a basic lighting equipment. I bought some pre-owned softboxes and tripods, also some Yongnuo 560 Mk III. Now I'm looking for an adapter that I can use to put a softbox onto my tripod and use a speedlite in it. The softbox has a round metal mount (9.5 centimeter in diameter). Can someone give me a hint how these mounts are called and/or what adapters I can use? Thanks in advance!

[image: Softbox]
[image: Tripod]
[image: Flash]

Comment: Could you eventually tell what kind of mount does your softbox have? Or what make and model your softbox is ?There are different adapters for each type of mount.

Comment: [Tripods](http://www.dpreview.com/articles/2812431567/five-of-the-best-tripods-for-under-450) or [lightstands](http://strobist.blogspot.com/2006/03/lighting-101-light-stands.html)? And if you don't know the make/model of the softbox, can you post a pic of the softbox mount?

Comment: I added some pictures. Unfortunately, I don't know the mount type (that's why I'm asking). The tripod (or is it a lightstand?) is a Walimex WT-806.

Comment: @Rob, the Walimex is a lightstand. I only asked because lightstands are topped with studs, while a tripod only has a threaded bolt--with tripods you need to screw on a stud to add the adapter. The links in my previous comment will show you what tripods look like vs. lightstands.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! You're right, of course, it looks different from the "real" tripod's head that I have for the camera.

Comment: You have two separate questions here — how to connect the softbox to the flash, and how connect the softbox to a light stand (which it is, in this case). The second is answered by [What are the connectors like on a “standard light stand”?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/60629/1943).

Comment: If the above link doesn't answer your question about the stand, could you edit it out of this question and ask it separately as a new one, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there really isn't one magic phrase you can google for that will conjure up a complete list of these things--the language changes a lot. But the words that will probably get you the best hits are "speedlite mount adapter". But you'll get a lot of other stuff that *isn't* what you're looking for.  It'll generally look something like this:

[image]

The ring attaches to the softbox mount, the speedlight is mounted on a coldshoe, and the base slips over the stud on top of the lightstand.

There are also a ton of variants, like the Neewer S-Type Bracket Holder with Bowens Mount, which mounts the flash horizontally, rather than vertically, and does not stress the foot of the flash.

But the main concern is to get one with a ring that attaches correctly to the (I'm guessing Bowens—hopefully someone else can confirm) mount on your softbox.

Comment: @Rob Good luck. I'm not at all familiar with speedrings, and have always just purchased speedlite stuff, so not sure how to tell the ring fits...

Comment: You need to measure the diameter of the outer ring, not the hole for the flash head. What you have is a standard bowens mount and these are typically 140-155 mm diameter to fit inside the ring adapter. Also, from your photo, it's an inside mount - which may not work with a speedlight bracket. You may need to mount the softbox with the ring outside, but that depends on the ring it that is possible.

Comment: I have a couple of [these](http://www.amazon.com/Neewer-Bracket-Speedlite-Reflector-Umbrella/dp/B00JAAXH1A/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1452115120&sr=8-1&keywords=s-type) which will work with your Bowens mount and are very solid.

Comment: @Robin Thanks. That's what the "variant" link in my answer went to until Neewer rotted out the link. I'm changing that link to the name in the Amazon listing.