# What is this screw on top of my tripod?

Tags: tripod, tripod-heads, tripod-socket, tripod-collar

I recently acquired this tripod and was wondering what this screw is and what I need to do to make this tripod usable with a DSLR.

The screw seems to be a bit wider than half an inch.

What kind of adapter might I need to fit a common tripod head?

[image: Said Tripod]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a standard tripod mount?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17816/is-there-a-standard-tripod-mount)

Comment: Covered by the earlier question — this isn't the standard thread for attaching a camera to a tripod, but is typical for attaching tripod legs to heads.

Comment: Stating the make and model of the tripod will make your question more specific and may shed some more light as to what type of heads are available.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know the make of the tripod , it doesn't seem to be anywhere on the body.

Comment: I might also be misunderstanding how to measure the bolt. The width of the bolt is 1/2" but does that translate in some way to a 3/8" "thread"?

Comment: It's not covered by the earlier question, the earlier question asks about a standard for the tripod mount, this question doesn't know what is expected to be attached. I don't see the duplication.

Answer (score 2):

Basically they sell you either a incomplete tripod or you just need to buy a tripod head:

https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=tripod+head

There are several options to choose from and some brands sell the tripods and heads as separate parts.

Comment: Yes. That threaded piece is where the head assembly attaches. The head assembly holds the camera.

Comment: I have a tripod head but this screw is too large for it. I believe that in general tripod heads require a 1/4" screw and this one is much bigger than that. Slightly over 1/2" wide.

Comment: Have you tried unscrewing it? There is a slim chance it is an adapter and there is a smaller screw underneath.

Comment: @y4ku Are you sure it isn't 3/8"-16? Again, see [this earlier answer](http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/17817/1943).

Comment: I've tried unscrewing it and can't seem to get it off. The earlier answer doesn't quite answer my question with any certainty, it is a description of two standards that exist. I'm going to pick up a 3/8" to 1/4" converter to see if this is the case. Until then, this is still a mystery.