# Will Joby Gorillapod SLR Zoom work with mirrorless Olympus EM10?

Tags: tripod, olympus, mirrorless, gorillapod

I looked at the Joby Gorillapod Hybrid, which lists mirrorless support but would only hold 1kg. The SLR Zoom would hold 3kg which I prefer. However, it only lists DSLRs as supported. Will it work with the mirrorless too? Is the threading standardised / always the same?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. From the [specification](http://joby.com/gorillapod/hybrid) for the Gorillapod:

> Connection Point:     ¼"-20  standard tripod mount

And see [Is there a standard tripod mount?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17816/is-there-a-standard-tripod-mount) — this is the standard thread, which is near-universal. It's not listed in Olympus's [E-M10 specs](http://www.getolympus.com/us/en/e-m10.html), possibly because it's *so* assumed. You can see from, for example, [this review](http://www.photographyblog.com/reviews/olympus_om_d_e_m10_review/) that the camera does have a tripod socket — and it's definitely safe to assume that it's the standard one (and the review notes that this is in line with the lens mount, which is convenient for alignment — not the case on some compact cameras).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will work.

ALL cameras have a standard tripod mounting thread.

(unless they don't have one at all)