# How to fit mobile onto gorillapod 3k kit

Tags: gorillapod

I have a nikon d3300 for the gorillapod 3k kit. I want to be able to mount mobile on it as well. What do i need. I cannot seem to find any clear instructions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screw on top of tripods that attaches to cameras is a standard size: 1/4-20 UNC. See: [Is there a standard tripod mount?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17816/is-there-a-standard-tripod-mount)

What you need is a **phone tripod mount** that has the standard 1/4-20 hole to receive the tripod's screw. You don't need to worry about specifying the screw size — it's a standard. If you find a phone tripod mount with a threaded hole in the bottom (almost all of them have one—it wouldn't be a *tripod* adapter without it, after all), it will mount on the Gorillapod's base plate.

Comment: Can you show me example link please

Comment: Example: https://www.reallyrightstuff.com/Mobile-Phone-Clamp-Stand?quantity=1&custcol43=5&custcol45=1