# Good way to make a standard camera strap attachable to Godox TT850 and clones?

Tags: off-camera-flash, godox

The common TT850, their clones and related designs have no lugs to attach a strap directly, nor small lugs (like an old school Metz 45 has) where you could attach a key ring or other strap attachment.

While drilling a hole and attaching some kind of eye bolt would work, that might not even be that stable given the plastic case material - or lead to interesting electrical safety problems.

Rubber band or cable tie hacks are likely not very reliable.

Is there some well known trick, especially given that these flash units are probably more useful as hand held off camera flashes than on camera...

EDIT: Idea is to be able to have a hand free when needed, without needing an assistant, while having a charged and accessorized (in the worst case, with a 20 inch softbox) flash within hands reach immediately. Which I would assume to be a very common need in all kinds of indoor reportage scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

Profoto make a [case with a shoulder strap](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1357076-REG/profoto_340217_a1_bag_with_shoulder.html) for their A1 flash. I'm sure there are similar cheap knockoffs somewhere.

Godox makes a [similar type bag](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07Q6RSFM1) for their much larger AD600 Pro.

Many lens cases come with shoulder straps, Some might be the right size for your flashes.

I just use the cases that come with my Yongnuo and Canon speedlights. They have belt loops on the back of the case, and it is pretty easy to holster/unholster them when they are attached to my belt (either the one holding up my pants or a separate [camera belt](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XPQ3327) for holding lens and accessory cases). You could probably just run the ends of a conventional camera strap through the belt loop and connect the two 3/8" ends through a single one of the loop buckles that come on each end of the strap.

It's not exactly a strap attachment, but there may be another way to get where you're trying to go.

Spider makes a product called the [*Spider Monkey*](https://spiderholster.com/product/spider-monkey-holster-kit/) for attaching speedlights and other accessories directly to a belt. These look to be not much more than an old fashioned ["universal" phone swivel belt clip](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00FH45MXO) with an adhesive tab that sticks to the back of a phone.

[image]

Stick the tab to your flash instead, put the clip on your belt, and you're done.

An earlier version of the Spider Monkey used a velcro strap to hold the tab to the flash.

[image]

Take a wide flash accessory strap with velcro connectors on each end, cut an appropriately sized vertical slit in it, and use the tab with or without the adhesive as an additional way to secure the flash.

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried this, but I think the Frio Cold Shoe Adapter would do the trick. See [Is there a simple flash bracket which holds a flash securely?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/16420/1943) — 8ts a plastic shoe which snaps securely to the flash"s foot. There's space near the front which you could fit a thin strap though, or you could get a threaded pin to attach to a wider strap.