# What flash should I get for my Samsung mirrorless?

Tags: flash, hotshoe-flash, samsung

I want to start and try using a flash for my photos.
Since I never used more than build-in flashes of compact cameras, I am completely new to the topic of choosing the right flash for me.

After some reading I'm still not quite sure of what I should or can even use.
The different camera manufacturers are using slightly different hot shoes/methods of communication between flash and camera, is that right?

I own a Samsung NX300m. Does that mean I can only use flashes explicitly built/modified for NX cameras?
Since of course nobody wants to make flashes for cameras that do not get produced anymore, in that case there wouldn't be a big range of flashes for me.

Does anything of this change if I use a remote trigger?

Answer (score 0):

As you camera has a hotshoe you can use any external flash + radio trigger that fits your camera, for example a generic one.

Take a look at some other questions. Some are focused on portrait but you can start there. It is almost the same as lighting for still life for example.

[What's a decent lighting kit for getting started with portraits?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15804/whats-a-decent-lighting-kit-for-getting-started-with-portraits)

Comment: "...you can use any external flash + radio trigger..." That depends on whether you want the camera and flash to be able to communicate beyond the signal to "fire" the flash.